# How can I download mp3 from server using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to download mp3 from the server and save it in the local folder but it is not downloaded, Why?

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String MP3_URL = "http://aylaappcollection.com/wallpaper/ringtone/57798_V0pBniyjB9.mp3";

    private File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Create Folder
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder 2021");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        new DownloadMP3().execute();

    }

    private class DownloadMP3 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.w("ABC","1");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urlParams) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(MP3_URL);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                // downlod the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath() + "Test 2021.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.w("ABC","2 " + s);
        }

    }

}
```

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't know if there any mistake in the code or no, I hope you help me, Thank You.

....................................................................................................

Comment: if(!file.mkdir()){Toast(...sorry could not create directory..); return;}  I think i told you that before.

Comment: `catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
            return null;` Dont ignore that exception. Handle it decently and return something. I also told you that before. Why are you not adapting your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160866/unable-to-download-mp3-files-from-the-server-for-the-devices-that-have-api-29

Comment: @blackapps Thanks